# ddply multifactorial all pairwise t-tests

Tags: r, plyr

How to perform a multifactorial t-test for all possible pairs of groups with a minimal number of coding lines.

My example:
3x features : 1,2,3 
4x groups: : A,B,C,D

Aim: For each feature test all pairs of groups:

1(A-B,A-C,A-D,B-C,B-D,C-D) 
2(A-B,A-C,A-D,B-C,B-D,C-D) 
3(A-B,A-C,A-D,B-C,B-D,C-D)
= 18 T-tests

At the moment I am using ddply and inside lapply :

```
library(plyr)

groupVector <- c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10))
featureVector <- rep(1:3,each=40)

mydata <- data.frame(feature=factorVector,group=groupVector,value=rnorm(120,0,1))

ddply(mydata,.(feature),function(x){
  grid <- combn(unique(x$group),2, simplify = FALSE)
  df <- lapply(grid,function(p){
    sub <- subset(x,group %in% p)
    pval <- t.test(sub$value ~ sub$group)$p.value
    data.frame(groupA=p[1],groupB=p[2],pval=pval)
  })
  res <- do.call("rbind",df)
  return(res)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, although it's arguable whether it's 'better'

```
split.data <- split(mydata, mydata$feature)
pairs <- as.data.frame(matrix(combn(unique(mydata$group), 2), nrow=2))
library(tidyverse)
map_df(split.data, function(x) map_df(pairs, function(y) tibble(groupA = y[1], groupB = y[2], 
                                        pval = t.test(value ~ group, data = x, subset = which(x$group %in% y))$p.value)), .id="feature")
```

Output

```
# # A tibble: 18 x 4
   # feature groupA groupB       pval
     # <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
 # 1       1      A      B 0.28452419
 # 2       1      A      C 0.65114472
 # 3       1      A      D 0.77746420
 # 4       1      B      C 0.42546791
 # 5       1      B      D 0.39876582
 # 6       1      C      D 0.88079645
 # 7       2      A      B 0.57843592
 # 8       2      A      C 0.30726571
 # 9       2      A      D 0.55457986
# 10       2      B      C 0.74871464
# 11       2      B      D 0.24017130
# 12       2      C      D 0.04252878
# 13       3      A      B 0.01355117
# 14       3      A      C 0.08746756
# 15       3      A      D 0.24527519
# 16       3      B      C 0.15130684
# 17       3      B      D 0.09172577
# 18       3      C      D 0.64206517
```